# How to make Serverside pagination work for datatable via external request

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

The title might not be apt one but I'm confused with serverside processing in datatable, I'm able to make it work but all the data are loading at once instead of paginating.

I'm actually making an request to an external url and retrieving data and not from a database.So once making request to the external url all data are returned at once, I'm able to retrieve total count for eg 8000. I'm setting 8000 as my "recordsTotal" but I have no idea what to give for recordsFiltered and how can I calculate it. Here pagecount is total data

```
        $endpoint = "https://41.72.XXX.XX:4300/XXX/XXX/XXXX.xsjs";
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->request('GET', $endpoint);  
        $res = (json_decode($response->getBody(), true));
        $pagecount = count($res['Results']); 

    $dataset = array(
                "draw"=>intval($request->draw),
                "recordsTotal" => intval($pagecount),
                "recordsFiltered"     =>  intval($pagecount),  
                "data" => $arraydata
            );
 echo json_encode($dataset);
```

since im not retrieving data from a database how can i make it work ? im using laravel and via ajax i send request.

```
$('#sapordersTable').dataTable({
            "processing": true,
             "serverSide":true,
            "draw":1,
            "ajax": {
        url: '{{ ('orders') }}',
        type: 'POST',
       },
            "columns": [
                {data: 'CustomerName'},
                {data: 'Customer_Code'},
                {data: 'DocEntry'},
                {data: 'Order_Date'},
                {data: 'Order_Branch'}
            ],
            
        });
    });
```

Comment: Since you are using laravel take a look at the collection method [forpage](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-forpage). One of the parameters that datatables would send is the page number in this case as well

Comment: @apokryfos Could you provide any example

Comment: It really depends on how your resultset looks like say your data is in `$res['data']` then you could probably do: `"data" => collect($res['data'])->skip(request()->start??0)->take(request()->length??10)` where 10 here would be the default page size if one is not specified. What datatables sends to the server is described at https://datatables.net/manual/server-side